# Rails Render Index with URL Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

At my work, we are in the middle of breaking up our Rails monolith. We are currently serving our react app through the asset pipeline. I am implementing JWT for authentication. I am trying to pass the token in the url without using sessions/cookies as part of an admin impersonating a user.

```
class ReactPagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :index #this will open up the react app
  end
end
```

Is it possible to render a view and pass along parameters in the url?

I want this to open up the index page with url parameter (i.e. `localhost:4000/users?jwt=abc.def.ghi`

I've tried doing something like `render :index, jwt: abc.def.ghi`, but that doesn't work. Is the only way to do this via `redirect_to`?

Comment: What is it, precisely, you are trying to do? This sounds potentially like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @jvillian At my work, we currently have a react app that we load from the asset pipeline. This route that I posted opens the react app, but I need to pass along an auth token (without using cookies/sessions since the end goal is to eventually move the react app into a node application and serve it on aws). I'll update my question to include some context

Answer (score 1):

You are actually defining a redirection:

- You want to go to `localhost:4000/users`
- The page display the index page, and URL becomes `localhost:4000/users?id=123`

For the normal webpage, changing URL will make the browser redirect. As you can see the result when executing this JS in the Chrome Console:

```
window.location.href = "google.com"
```

the browser will redirect you to `google.com`

So, for a Rails's application, **you should do a redirection** by `redirect_to` to achieve the current needs.

However, if you really want to change the URL without redirection, you can do it via Javascript. Just use `window.history` to change your URL

Your controller:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def index
  @desired_id = 123
end
```

and your view

```
<%-# app/views/users/index.html.erb %>
<!-- rest of HTML -->
<script>
  window.history.pushState("", "", "?id=<%= j @desired_id %>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use redirect_to

```
redirect_to users_url, id: 5
```

will get you to `/users?id=5`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, render is for rending the view and has nothing to do with the setting the url.
[ruby docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render)